# Asp.Net MVC Rollback Changes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, transactions, rollback

Suppose, I have an action which is updating lots of tables. E.g.

```
public action Save()
{
    Employee Emp = new Employee();
    Emp.Name = "Test";
    db.Employees.Add(emp);
    db.SaveChanges();

    Job job = new Job();
    Job.Name = "Test";
    db.Jobs.Add(job);
    db.SaveChanges();

    Status status = new Status();
    status.Name = "Test";
    db.Status.Add(status);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

First of all, I know I should call `db.SaveChanges()` only once, but I am talking about complex scenarios. Or I should `DbContextTransaction` so I can `commit` or `rollback` transactions.

Suppose, I follow my code approach and there is any problem in the second query, then the first query transaction will not be `rollback` and the third query will not be executed.

I just want to know is there any other approach, except those two I mentioned above to execute all if there is no bug in any queries otherwise don't execute any.

Comment: [Use a `TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why does a complex scenario mean that db.SaveChanges() is called more than once?  What does that mean?

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is using EF (though TBF he doesn't actually specify what any of these methods do or how the SQL is actually executed)

Comment: If you have FK in any of the updates, then ensure that the objects themselves are related properly before calling SaveChanges(). If you wish to ensure that no data is updated unless all data is updated, i.e. you need to save to get a value from the database to use in a later save, place all changes in a transaction.

Comment: Yes @Fran calling more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one `SaveChanges()` as follows. If it succeeds it will update all the table..If it fails for one then it will fails for all and rollback..May be you are aware of it. but would you tell me please in what exact real life situation you need what you specified in your question?

```
public action Save()
{
    Employee Emp = new Employee();
    Emp.Name = "Test";
    db.Employees.Add(emp);

    Job job = new Job();
    Job.Name = "Test";
    db.Jobs.Add(job);


    Status status = new Status();
    status.Name = "Test";
    db.Status.Add(status);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```